# how to import a react 3rd party library into the project (the library uses module.exports but in react we use import syntax)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to import a react 3rd party library into the project (the library uses module.exports but in react we use import syntax)

Library which i want to use inside my react project is mentioned below : -

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/os

Can i please get some help !!

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are transpiled so you can easily use them.

just install them with `npm install`

and then import/require it

```
const si = require('systeminformation');

// promises style - new since version 3
si.cpu()
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

all is here in readme https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation

Comment: But if i am importing it, it doesn't work that way out --> i am also attaching a codeSandbox link it will be really great help if u can tell me where do i need to do the changes so that i can see those information fetched by this lib --> https://codesandbox.io/s/system-information-9lgrdi